# Is there a way to sum multiple SUMIF statements without writing each one individually?

Tags: excel

I have two sheets. The first (Sheet 1) with a column of lookups and the second (Sheet 2) with a column of lookups and a column of values.

Sheet 2 includes many more observations than Sheet 1, but I only care about the data from the observations listed in Sheet 1.

I want to get a sum of all the values in Sheet 2 matching all the lookups in Sheet 1 without have to write a chain of a few hundred SUMIF statements.

I could really use your help.

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: This really needs sample data and expected results.  Hard to provide an accurate answer otherwise.

Comment: I will get on that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could do it without a helper column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,Sheet2!$B:$B))
```

Comment: I was just about to post this answer. This is what you're looking for!

Comment: This is working, but for some reason it is returning different values than I was expecting. But it is probably something wrong in my sheet. This does the job! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Use a helper column in sheet 1:

Use the following formula in `B3`:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A3,Sheet2!B:B)
```

And populate down

Then `SUM` these values

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, and I did do that. But I am wondering if there is a way to skip the helper column since this is for data validation and, simply put, there is no pretty way to include the helper column. But I really appreciate the response!! c:

Comment: You could hide the helper column or have it on a different (hidden) sheet

Answer (score -1):

Yes, with an array formula, but it's not still perfect:

Let's say your data looks like this (copied your image):

[image]

You can use this **array formula**:

`=SUM(IF($D$2:$D$10={1;2;3};$E$2:$E$10))`

> Because this is an **array formula** it must entered pressing
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or it won't work!

Notice the lookup values are the numbers between `{...}` in the formula.

Hope you can adap this to your needs.

Comment: Can I reference cells in the array? Like `{$A$3:$A$5}` or `{$A$3; $A$4; $A$5}? Excel is not letting me do so.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't